# Are ‘in die Stadt fahren’ and ‘ins Zentrum fahren’ the same?

Tags: meaning, difference, noun

Please explain whether in German the phrase *in die Stadt fahren* is the same as *in das Zentrum fahren.* My course’s exam today had shown both these places as the same. I had thought *Stadt* and *Zentrum* are different. Driving in the city should be different from driving to the centre of the city. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

The word **Zentrum** is mostly limited to written texts. People would rather say **Innenstadt** or **Stadtmitte**. When coming from outside town, there's little reason to assume you would go to the suburbs when saying *Ich fahre in die Stadt*. If you do, you would use the name of the particular suburb instead. So *Stadt* replaces *Innenstadt* here.

Comment: "When coming from outside town" - this can even be a matter of perspective. Someone who lives in a quarter that is somewhat "rural" and not in the city centre might consider themselves to live "außerhalb der Stadt", even though their quarter is formally a part of the city.

Comment: I disagree that *Zentrum* is limited to written texts in all cases and cities.

Answer (score 3):

Es hängt von Stadt und den Umständen ab.

Berlin hat beispielsweise 2 Zentren, eins im Westen, eins im Osten.

Dann hängt es davon ab, wo der Sprecher ist. Wenn er außerhalb der Stadt ist, dann kann das Überqueren der Stadtgrenze als in die Stadt fahren verstanden werden. Wohnt man eh in der Stadt, aber in einer Wohnsiedlung am Stadtrand, kann *in die Stadt* ein Synonym fürs Zentrum sein.

Insbesondere kann die Situation so sein, dass sich aus ihr ergibt, was gemeint ist, etwa wenn eine Familie zum Einkaufen entweder in den Laden außerhalb der Stadt, oder ins Geschäft in der Stadtmitte fährt, und jemand, von dem man weiß, er will einkaufen, sagt, dass er in die Stadt fährt.

Es sind aber auch Siedlungen denkbar, die ein Zentrum haben, aber keine Stadt sind.

Comment: »Es sind aber auch Siedlungen denkbar, die ein Zentrum haben, aber keine Stadt sind« – zum Beispiel Murnau. Oder Garmisch. Ob Partenkirchen auch ein Zentrum hat, weiß ich nicht auswendig.

Comment: Ein Dorfplatz ist per Definition ein Zentrum einer nicht-Stadt.

Comment: Gehe ich recht in der Annahme, daß ein Einwohner von Berlin-Spandau,
der "in die Stadt" fährt, nach Spandau-Zentrum will, während
er, wenn er zum Kudamm oder zum Alex will, "nach Berlin" fährt?
(So funktioniert das jedenfalls in [Hamburg-Harburg](http://www.zeit.de/2015/48/hamburg-harburg-stadtteil-image/seite-2), und so
kenne ich es auch aus meiner Geburtsstadt.)

Answer (score 2):

Some answers here claim that *ins Zentrum fahren* be unidiomatic or never heard. To get that out of the way: while it is generally true it is not always true. Depending on the city in question and the people saying it, the more common phrase for *going to the centre* can indeed be *ins Zentrum fahren.* I will admit, though, that it is more common in most cities to say *Innenstadt, Stadtmitte* — or maybe you use a name of an actual borough or a prominent place in the centre instead.

Now that that has been said let’s look at the differences between the two. No matter where you’re coming from, *ins Zentrum fahren* will always go to the *centre.* That means a couple of things:

- for cities like Salzgitter, which do not have an established city centre, you cannot say *ins Zentrum fahren*
- if you are coming from way outside the city and you are just going to a suburb (which already belongs to the city but is away from the centre) you again cannot use it.

What exactly is meant by *in die Stadt fahren* depends a lot on who says it. going from more central to less central:

- if you already live in the centre you probably won’t use it because you’re already there. However, you may say things like:

  > Ich wohne in der Stadt.
- If you live in a borough of the city that is not exactly the centre (e.g. Munich Pasing), you would most likely use it exactly in the sense of *ins Zentrum fahren* — i.e. you’re going to visit the city centre.
- If you live just outside the city (often, but not always delimited by political boundaries; however, suburbs that are more like outside villages count here, too), it can either mean *going into the city at all* (i.e. going *any* place in the city’s boundaries) or as above going to the city centre.
- And finally, if you live far out of town (at least ten minutes drive) you would use it for every trip inside the city’s boundaries, even if you’re just visiting a friend who lives on the very outskirts.

For the second group, both phrases are equal, for the third group, they are practically equal. The first won’t use either and for the fourth they have different meanings (akin to the difference between *city* and *city centre)*

Answer (score 0):

‘Ins Zentrum fahren’ has the connotations of to go "downtown."

‘In die Stadt fahren’ technically means "to go into the city," so you have a point there.

But its current connotation is also "to go downtown." For our purposes they are the same, nowadays. That might not have been true 50 or 100 years ago.

Comment: Not quite, it’s perfectly fine to say ‘Ich fahre in die Stadt’ coming from the countryside if you’re just going to a suburb.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are absolutely right. To say
`in das Zentrum fahren` is very uncommon in spoken language, as a native speaker I even never heard it before (but it's grammatically correct).
`in die Stadt fahren` is for cities, for villages you say `in das Dorf gehen`

Comment: I would not say that *ins (in das) Zentrum fahren* is very uncommon. It is often used for instance when describing how to get from the airport to the city center of a larger city.   *In die Stadt fahren* to me would be most typically used in the context of shopping in the city.

Comment: Yes, you are right. _Zentrum_ is very formal (for example in a hotel's name).